# FormFooter Visible property - Proportion form height accordingly

Tags: ms-access, vba

When trying to toggle the FormFooter's `visible` property, how do you ensure that when the footer is switched to visible=Yes that it grows out the bottom of the form rather than growing in to the Detail section of the form?

I've tried setting `CanGrow` properties of all sections to yes. I've even tried to update the `height` property of the Details section to the additional proportion taken up by the height of the footer section when it is visible. Neither of these work and there doesn't seem to be an overall form height property that I can adjust via VBA.

I'm looking to hide a section of controls in a pop-up form that are only revealed when the user clicks a button. Was hoping to do this in the foot section and then simply use the command button to toggle the FormFooter's `visible` property, but can't seem to do this without it either encroaching on the Detail section or adding a scroll bar to the Detail section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to avoid cannibalizing the form's `Detail` area when you make the `FormFooter` visible.  The only way I know to do that is to increase the form's `WindowHeight` by the amount (`FormFooter.Height`) needed to accommodate the footer.

However, the `WindowHeight` property is read-only, so you can't change it directly.  Instead, you can use the form's `Move` method to resize the form.  Resizing the form *indirectly* changes the `WindowHeight` property value.

This VBA procedure did what I think you want when tested in Access 2007.  And it did that for my pop-up form without causing any noticeable display flicker, which was a pleasant surprise.

```vb
Private Sub cmdToggleFooter_Click()
    Dim lngWindowHeight As Long

    If Me.FormFooter.Visible = True Then
        ' reduce WindowHeight by FormFooter.Height
        lngWindowHeight = Me.WindowHeight - Me.FormFooter.Height
    Else
        ' increase WindowHeight by FormFooter.Height
        lngWindowHeight = Me.WindowHeight + Me.FormFooter.Height
    End If
    ' adjust form's window size
    Me.Move Left:=Me.WindowLeft, Height:=lngWindowHeight
    ' toggle FormFooter.Visible
    Me.FormFooter.Visible = Not Me.FormFooter.Visible
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you. Regarding the scroll bar: I was just saying that although the user can still access the parts of the details section taken-up by the footer using the scroll bar that will appear, I'd prefer the window to resize without the need for a scroll bar.

Comment: That makes sense to me now, thanks.  Sorry I didn't grok it yesterday.  BTW, you could generalize that procedure and store it in a standard module so you could conveniently implement the feature for other forms.  `ToggleFooter(ByRef frm As Form)`, then replace `Me.` with `frm.` in the body of the procedure.  And your command button click event could then be `ToggleFooter Me`  I may use that myself, so thanks for asking this question.  :-)

Comment: does the `Me.Move` not work under certain circumstances? I'm trying to use it to position this form closer to the top of the screen by putting `Me.Move Left:=WindowLeft, Top:=1` in the form's Open event. I've turned the form's autocenter property off, but the form still opens in the centre of the screen.

Comment: Check the form's `Moveable` property from VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Have the footer visible at design time, so that it is visible (very briefly, at worst) when the form is being loaded. Then put a FormFooter.Visible=false in the Form Load.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately the thing happens (detail section gets squashed when I wake the footer visible via a command button procedure).